# validate string data using regex which allowed only numbers and - (hyphen) of length 6 but hypen should not be the end and the digits not same

Tags: regex

Validate the string using the regex which has the - (hypen)

Requirement is : string contains only digits and - (hyphens) and not end with - (hyphen) and all other digits not be the same.

```
^([0-9-])(?!\1+$)[0-9-]{5}$
```

The above one allow only digits and hyphen but its not restricted end with hyphen and check all other digits are same.

ex:

```
1111-1 Not allowed because all are same digits 
1111-2 Allowed
11112- Not allowed as its end with - Hypen
-12345 Not allowed as its start with - hypen
```

Comment: ^[0-9](?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$)(?=.{5}$)[0-9]*(?:-[0-9]*){0,4}[0-9]+$

Comment: Note the requirement of "digits not the same" promotes the problem out of a DFA/NFA/CFG, such that it is no longer context-free. In this sense, a regex would be a much more complicated solution than direct string parsing.

Comment: You're going to need a 2 stage solution.  Testing for the format of the string is easy enough `\d{4}-\d`  To test for digit diversity you'll need a second step inspecting the string.

Answer (score 2):

You might write the pattern as

```
^(\d)(?!(?:\1|-)+$)(?!\d*-\d*-)[\d-]{4}\d$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d)` Capture a single digit in group 1
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `(?:\1|-)+$` Check that to the right there is not only the group 1 value or hyphens
- `(?!\d*-\d*-)` Assert not 2 hyphens
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[\d-]{4}` Match 4 digits or hyphens
- `\d` Match a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4wypaK/1)

If there should be at least 1 hyphen:

```
^(\d)(?!(?:\1|-)+$)(?=\d*-)[\d-]{4}\d$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a5qTXp/1)

Comment: You could add the 2nd negative lookahead as an alternative: `^(\d)(?!(?:\1|-)+$|\d*-\d*-)[\d-]{4}\d$`. Saves a few steps =)

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents to allow `[01]` hyphens:

```
^(?=.{6}$)(\d)(?=.*(?!\1)\d)\d+(?:-\d+)?$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uFFcoF/1)